# SQL Server Recursive CTE for finding all the dependencies

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, sql-server-2012, common-table-expression

I have a table with the following data.

```
Road    City
R1      C1
R2      C2
R3      C1
R3      C3
R4      C3
R4      C5
R5      C5
```

If R1 is the input I need to get R1, R3, R4 and R5 as the output. This is because R1 belongs to C1 and C1 has R3 and R3 also belongs to C3 which has R4 and similarly R5.

I was trying to make use of CTE recursion but not able to get it to work. I tried stored procedure recursive call but it goes only 30 levels deep.

```
with tmp1 as (
select ROAD, CITY, 1 as Level from table R1 WHERE ROAD = 1712
UNION ALL
select R2.ROAD, R2.CITY,Level + 1 as Level 
from  tmp1  INNER JOIN table R2 ON tmp1.CITY = R2.CITY and tmp1.ROAD <> R2.ROAD   
)
select * from tmp1  
OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
```

Any thoughts greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you please share the SP which you wrote and we can try to enhance that.Thanks

Comment: SP doesn't work as data is more than 30 levels deep.

Comment: Added the CTE I was working on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive CTE will not work without some way of breaking cycles. Other database vendors have specific features for disallowing a row to be added twice. Unless something was added in the latest releases, Microsoft SQL Server does not.

The following does not work, because the recursive clause is referring to the CTE twice. (Or it contains a subquery)

```
WITH recur AS (SELECT Road, City 
    FROM @Map
    WHERE Road = @StartingRoad
    --
    UNION ALL
    --
    SELECT next.Road, next.City
    FROM @Map next
    INNER JOIN recur
        ON (recur.City = next.City AND recur.Road <> next.Road)
        OR (recur.City <> next.City AND recur.Road = next.Road)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
        FROM recur test
        WHERE test.Road = next.Road AND test.City = next.City))
SELECT *
FROM recur;
```

> Msg 253, Level 16, State 1, Line 36
>   Recursive member of a common table expression 'recur' has multiple recursive references.

It is possible with a straight forward loop, which you could stick in a stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @Map TABLE (Road VARCHAR(2), City VARCHAR(2));
INSERT INTO @Map (Road, City)
VALUES ('R1', 'C1')
    , ('R2', 'C2')
    , ('R3', 'C1')
    , ('R3', 'C3')
    , ('R4', 'C3')
    , ('R4', 'C5')
    , ('R5', 'C5');

DECLARE @StartingRoad VARCHAR(2) = 'R1';

DECLARE @Results TABLE (Road VARCHAR(2), City VARCHAR(2));
INSERT INTO @Results (Road, City)
SELECT Road, City
FROM @Map
WHERE Road = @StartingRoad

WHILE (1=1) BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO @Results (Road, City)
    SELECT next.Road, next.City
    FROM @Map next
    INNER JOIN @Results r
        ON (r.City = next.City AND r.Road <> next.Road)
        OR (r.City <> next.City AND r.Road = next.Road)
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
        FROM @Results test
        WHERE test.Road = next.Road AND test.City = next.City);
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        BREAK;
END;

SELECT DISTINCT Road
FROM @Results
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will try this out.

Comment: There were some performance issues so I modified this and got it worked. Many thanks for the solution. {WHILE (1=1) BEGIN 
    DELETE ##ROUTES OUTPUT DELETED.* INTO  ##RESULTS
    FROM ##ROUTES NEXT 
    LEFT JOIN ##RESULTS R1 ON R1.CITY = NEXT.CITY
 LEFT JOIN ##RESULTS R2 ON  R2.ROAD = NEXT.ROAD
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM ##RESULTS TEST WHERE TEST.ROAD = NEXT.ROAD AND TEST.CITY = NEXT.CITY)
 AND (R1.CITY IS NOT NULL OR R2.CITY IS NOT NULL);
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        BREAK;
END;}

Answer (score 0):

This might get you partially there. I am doing a partial Cartesian join to generate the city/road combinations, and artificially restricting the recursion to 20 levels. I can't help but think there is a better way.

```
WITH cte(road,
         city,
         connected_city,
         connected_road)
     AS (
     SELECT a.road,
            a.city,
            b.city AS connected_city,
            b.Road connected_road
     FROM deleteme a
          INNER JOIN deleteme b ON a.City = b.City
     WHERE a.road <> b.road)
     SELECT DISTINCT
            road
     FROM cte;

road
R1
R3
R4
R5
```